"Tiling the plane" with bricks of size $2 \times n$ (Domino tiling with rectangles?)
I was at a lecture today, where the teacher gave as an example, the way of tiling (in?) the plane with bricks of size $2 \times n$. I was never really clear exactly what she meant, or how one was supposed to count arrangements as the same or different, but the setup was sort of, like this:
We define a function $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ that counts, for $n$ bricks, the number of ways we can tile. Fix some number $n$ so that we have bricks/rectangles of sides $2 \times n$.
Furthermore, we let $f(0) := 1$. We then have

$f(1) = 1$,
$f(2) = 2$,
Generally, we have $$f(n) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} \binom{n-k}{k}. \qquad (1)$$

So, in this case (if I understood the lecturer correctly), for 3 bricks, we would have
\begin{align*}
f(3) &= \binom{3}{0}+\binom{2}{1}\\
&= 1+2\\
&= 3. 
\end{align*}
But this does not seem right to me, I can think of atleast $6$ ways to arrange the $3$ bricks, so the lecturer must be identifying different arrangements as the same? I think I've seen this in an earlier course on combinatorics I've taken, but I can't remember how to reason about this. I suppose this is called "Domino tiling" (with rectangles).
I'd be happy for any input.
(I'd also be very interested in an explanation from where this formula comes, since this is also something I did not understand; for example, where does the floor-formula in the index of the sum of $(1)$ come from?).

Can you state the 6 ways that you're thinking of for a $ 2 \times 3$ rectangle?

You describe the problem with 'the way of tiling the plan with bricks of size $2 \times n$ ; but finally, the problem is totally different ; we consider a rectangle with size $2 \times n$, and we are interesting with tiling this rectangle with dominos with size $2 \times 1$. Maybe this confusion is part of your mis-understanding.

@Lourrran Yep, I think so. Although I don't recall the teacher saying anything about the dimensions of the dominos, and neither whether we are allowed to rotate the dominos. But this might well be what the teacher had in mind (the problem formulation you and others have given).

I think that in tiling context, the word Domino is clearly define : a domino is a rectangle with size $2 \times 1$. This definition is standard. We can also (rarely) have a variant, where we explicitly say a domino-a-b, which means that we do not consider standard dominos, but dominos with size $a \times b$ ; Of course , we are allowed to rotate dominos. If not, if dominos cannot rotate, we have only 1 way of tiling a rectangle (or 0 if we are not lucky). A domino has 2 positions : horizontal or vertical.

Here's my best guess.
The question is to find the number of ways $f(n)$ to tile a $2\times n$ rectangle using dominos of size $1\times 2$.
There is clearly just one way to do this if $n=1$ (one domino) and two ways for $n=2$ (two horizontal dominos, or two vertical dominos).
For larger $n$, we can count as follows. The tiling will always consist of some vertical dominos and some $2\times2$ blocks of two horizontal dominos. Call one of these blocks of two horizontal dominos an "h-block." There can be anywhere from one to $\lfloor {n\over 2}\rfloor$ h-blocks. Denote a vertical tile as v for a "v-block."
How many ways are there to tile the $2\times n$ rectangle using exactly $k$ h-blocks? This is the same question as how many ways there are to write $n$ as an ordered sum of 1s and 2s, using exactly $k$ 2s. (For example, $8 = 1 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 2 + 1$ would correspond to the tiling v,v,h,v,h,v. The number of v or h blocks to tile the $2\times n$ rectangle is $n-k$ blocks (think about it), and the number of ways to use these $n-k$ blocks ($k$ of which are h-blocks) is the same as the number of ways of designating where the $k$ h-blocks go, so this is the number of subsets of the $n-k$ block positions where the $k$-many h-blocks go, so that is $n-k\choose k$.
Summing this over all possible $k$ yields $$f(n) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} \binom{n-k}{k}.$$

As an aside, $f(n)$ could be further simplified greatly.

Very good, thanks, this made this much clearer to me =).

Well, I should say then, that we count vertical tiles (i.e. of dimension $2 \times 1$ as different from $1 \times 2$ tiles). I.e. we count them as different when tiling. I think this is an important distinction that I did not really understand at first. Like, we are not only counting how many bricks to use, but also whether or not they are vertical or horizontal (i.e. of dimension $1 \times 2$ or dimension $1 \times 2$). And ofc then we are looking more specifically at the case when we have $k$ $2 \times 2$ blocks of horizontal dominos (an "$h$-block" with your terminology).

Hm, I guess I fail to see how we get the last step, still, i.e. why we get $\binom{n-k}{k}$. It is clear in the case of number of ways to write $n$ as a sum of $1$:s and $2$:s, but $\ldots$

Oh, I think I (sort of) get it now. The trick is to convert it into a form where we only need to talk about # of blocks.

Hopefully you get it now. The key is that every possible tiling is a left-to-right sequence of (one vertical tile OR two horizontal tiles), and the sequences of these choices are distinct and exhaust all possible tilings. The vertical tile choice gets you 1 step towards $n$ and the two horizontal tiles choice gets you 2 steps towards $n$.

Yes, exactly @SteveKass! I agree. I see now that I made some typo in my $2^{\text{nd}}$ comment; I meant to say ”(i.e. of dimension $1 \times 2$ or dimension $2 \times 1$)”.
